# Problem when trying to disable button , sending null to function

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been working on my Store App for a time now. There is a button on my page with controlls the sizes from the T-Shirts. 
Like this:

[image]

As we can see in the image, when the size is at the first position or last position, the button is disabled because we cannot move that size anymore.
When I attempt to do so on my app, I get that:

```
The relevant error-causing widget was
EditItemSize
lib\…\components\sizes_form.dart:39
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      EditItemSize.build
package:loja_virtual_nnananene/…/components/edit_item_size.dart:60
#1      StatelessElement.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4648
#2      ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4574
#3      Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4267
#4      ComponentElement._firstBuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4553
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Null check operator used on a null value
The relevant error-causing widget was
EditItemSize
lib\…\components\sizes_form.dart:39
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Reloaded 1 of 784 libraries in 2.220ms.
```

This is my size_form, which builds the sizes in the page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/common/custom_drawer/custom_icon_button.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/item_size.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/product.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/screens/edit_product/components/edit_item_size.dart';
 
class SizesForm extends StatelessWidget {
  const SizesForm(this.product);
 
  final Product product;
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FormField<List<ItemSize>>(
      initialValue: List.from(product.sizes),
      builder: (state) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    'Tamanhos',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  ),
                ),
                CustomIconButton(
                  Icons.add,
                  Colors.black,
                  () {
                    state.value!.add(ItemSize());
                    state.didChange(state.value);
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: state.value!.map((size) {
                return EditItemSize(
                  ObjectKey(key),
                  size,
                  () {
                    state.value!.remove(size);
                    state.didChange(state.value);
                  },
                  size != state.value!.first
                      ? () {
                          final index = state.value!.indexOf(size);
                          state.value!.remove(size);
                          state.value!.insert(index - 1, size);
                          state.didChange(state.value);
                        }
                      : null,
                  size != state.value!.last
                      ? () {
                          final index = state.value!.indexOf(size);
                          state.value!.remove(size);
                          state.value!.insert(index + 1, size);
                          state.didChange(state.value);
                        }
                      : null,
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is the item size tile, which build each row from the sizes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/common/custom_drawer/custom_icon_button.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/item_size.dart';
 
class EditItemSize extends StatelessWidget {
  const EditItemSize(
      Key key, this.size, this.onRemove, this.onMoveDown, this.onMoveUp);
 
  final ItemSize size;
  final VoidCallback? onRemove, onMoveUp, onMoveDown;
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 30,
          child: TextFormField(
            initialValue: size.name,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Título',
              isDense: true,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 4,
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 30,
          child: TextFormField(
            initialValue: size.stock.toString(),
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Estoque',
              isDense: true,
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 4,
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 40,
          child: TextFormField(
            initialValue: size.price.toStringAsFixed(2),
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Preço',
              isDense: true,
            ),
            keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
          ),
        ),
        CustomIconButton(
          Icons.remove,
          Colors.red,
          onRemove!,
        ),
        CustomIconButton(Icons.arrow_drop_up, Colors.black, onMoveUp!),
        CustomIconButton(Icons.arrow_drop_down, Colors.black, onMoveDown!)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I'm having problem in this specific part of the code:

```
 Column(
              children: state.value!.map((size) {
                var defaultSize;
                return EditItemSize(
                  ObjectKey(key),
                  size,
                  () {
                    state.value!.remove(size);
                    state.didChange(state.value);
                  },
                  state.value != null && size != state.value!.first
                      ? () {
                          final index = state.value!.indexOf(size);
                          state.value!.remove(size);
                          state.value!.insert(index - 1, size);
                          state.didChange(state.value);
                        }
                      : null,
                  state.value != null && size != state.value!.last
                      ? () {
                          final index = state.value!.indexOf(size);
                          state.value!.remove(size);
                          state.value!.insert(index + 1, size);
                          state.didChange(state.value);
                        }
                      : null,
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
```

If I remove the `size != state.value!.last` the code will work, but not the way it is supposed to

Comment: a simple solution could be `state.value != null && size != state.value!.last`

Comment: I will attempt so

Comment: @YuriHeiko That dind't work unfortunatlly

Comment: Could you show the changed code?

Comment: @YuriHeiko Sure, I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

## **EXPLANATION:**

This error occurs when you use a bang operator (!) on a nullable instance which wasn't initialized.

For example:

```
String? str; // Nullable String

void main() {
  int length = str!.length; // Bang ! operator is used before the field was initialized. 
}
```

You can tackle this problem by using a combination of `?.` and `??`

```
int stringLength =  str?.length ?? 0; // No error
```

The above code line has no error as in this case when `str` is null, the `.length` won't be called and so `str?.length` will be equivalent to `null` and since `stringLength` cannot be null, we provide a default value of `0`

Just to be more clear `??` is just a shorthand notation for null check.

For example:

`x = y ?? z` is equivalent to the below code:

```
if(y != null) {
x = y;
} 
else {
x = z;
}
```

## **SOLUTION:**

In your case if you replace `size != state.value!.last` with `size != (state.value?.last ?? defaultSize)` where defaultSize represents the default Size value which will be compared to the variable `size` when `state.value` is null.

If you totally want to skip comparing to a default size then you can do something like below:

```
(state.value != null ? (size != state.value!.last) : false) ? () 
{ 
  // add code here that you want to run if size != state.value!.last is true 
} : () {
    print ("size != state.value!.last was not satisfied");
}
```

Comment: What would be the default size? That's the problem, can I set it to P,M or G?

Comment: default size can be any static size that you would like. If you don't want that then you could do something like:

state.value != null && size != state.value!.last

Comment: I attempted to create a `var defaultValue` but it didn't work

Comment: `state.value != null && size != state.value!.last `this didn't work either

Comment: Just defining the var defaultValue won't work as it has no value.

Comment: I tried defining a `var defaultValue = 'p'`

Comment: Try this :

state.value != null ?  size != state.value!.last : false

Comment: How would I add that with the function? If you colud update the answer please. Since I have a function I can't simple insert that, and a bool type would not work with the Function()?

Comment: It half worked, I'm not getting errors, but the button is no changing the color when in first or last position

Comment: That is because the value state.value is actually null and that is why you got the error in the first place. Check your code to make sure the state.value has some data.